# xypic on Wordpress

Tags: latex

Is it possible to use xypic on Wordpress (for those who don't know what xypic is, it's a LaTex tool for drawing diagrams- see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Xy-pic))? On a related note, is it possible to use the LaTeX package chemfig on Wordpress?

Comment: You ask about tools that are not too close to typical WP functions/use cases. Not many people are going to be familiar with them and in such form it's asking someone else to plain do initial research for you. Are you _already_ using latex with WordPress? Which solutions you tried or at least found/considered?

Comment: There's the [QuickLaTeX](http://www.holoborodko.com/pavel/quicklatex/) plugin which uses a full TeX Live installation in the background. It looks like a very promising candidate. And if `xypic` doesn't work: TikZ does which as you might know is a *very* powerful drawing tool in LaTeX.